# Play framework : how to use "moreStyles" and "moreScripts"

Tags: java, templates, playframework

In the file `main.html`, in default project created by [Play!](http://www.playframework.org), there's this line :

```
#{get 'moreStyles' /}
```

I understand that if I need to add more styles, in my view script, I have to use

```
#{set tag:'value' /}
```

where `tag` should be `moreStyles`, but it seems worng to set the value to the full HTML `<link>` tag. And what happens if the view needs to add more styles, or scripts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

you set more styles with:

```
#{set 'moreStyles'}
        #{stylesheet 'main.css' /}
#{/set}
```

like scripts:

```
#{set 'moreScripts'}
    #{script 'base64.js'/}
#{/set}
```

Comment: I almost forgot about that question. I had found a similar solution on the user group, but the `#{script }` and `#{stylesheet }` was not mentioned. :)

Comment: This example works, but is only good for the simple case. If you intend to reuse this setter and expect the results to combine, see the other answer starring "simply using the #set..."

Answer (score 19):

simply using the #{set} tag will overwrite the previous values.

that is if you issue

```
#{set 'moreStyles'}xxx#{/set}
```

and then

```
#{set 'moreStyles'}yyy#{/set}
```

then

```
#{get 'moreStyles' /}
```

will only return yyy

in order to achieve what you want you have to

```
#{set 'moreStyles'}
    #{get 'moreStyles' /}
    #{stylesheet 'main.css' /}
#{/set}
```

and then the stylesheet main.css will be added to the previous value of morestyles

On a similar situation I ended up creating my own #{addStyle} tag

Comment: well, I didn't have such issue, but thank you for sharing this, If I ever come into this problem, I'll know what to do.

Comment: Just an FYI, I cut and pasted this into my code but all the play examples use 'moreStyles' in camel case and the set variable is case sensitive so 'morestyles' did not work.  Once I figured that out this example worked perfectly.

Comment: thanks, for the comment, if you are not depending on play samples the code above will work, but just to avoid confussion I'll edit it...

Comment: I agree with your comment about #{addStyle} I wrote append.html so I could use #{append 'moreStyles'}...#{/append} which contains:
    #{set _arg}#{get _arg /}#{doBody /}#{/set}

Answer (score 3):

```
#{set 'moreStyles'}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" charset="${_response_encoding}"/>
#{/set} 
#{set 'moreScripts'}
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="${_response_encoding}"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-zh-CN.js" type="text/javascript" charset="${_response_encoding}"></script>
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker();
    });
</script>
#{/set}
```