# Enlive templates – add to head section

Tags: clojure, enlive

Some pages of my app will have it's own js/css includes, so I wonder how I can add these resources to the head section of an html document with Enlive. I found 
"append" transformer, but there is no "html-append" without auto escaping. Or what a proper way to do that?

Comment: Do you have the include as a blob of HTML text or as a collection of urls or whatever? Oh and html-content is slooooooow.

Comment: I just want to add series of "<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/this-page-custom.css">" and js includes. I want to define these per page/template and use it when needed. For example, in Play! framework I use "moreScripts" placeholder in a base template and then I can add any script/style in derived views - (ex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276075/play-framework-how-to-use-morestyles-and-morescripts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers might predate enlive hiccup-style helpers. Answer taken and expanded from: [Enlive templating - Adding CSS includes to <head>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20811216/894091).

```
(require '[net.cgrand.enlive-html :as html])
```

Functions for generating HTML nodes (much much MUCH simpler):

```
(defn include-js [src]
      (first (html/html [:script {:src src}])))

(defn include-css [href]
      (first (html/html [:link {:href href :rel "stylesheet"}])))
```

Example usage:

```
;; Example templates/base.html file    
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>

(def jquery "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js") ; links work as well
(html/deftemplate home-page "templates/base.html"
  []
   [:head] (html/append (map include-css ["css/some_file" "css/index.css"]))
   [:head] (html/append (map include-js [jquery "js/index.js"])))
```

Check it produces the correct HTML:

```
(print (apply str (home-page)))
;; newlines added by hand for clarity
=> <html>
     <head>
       <link href="css/some_file" rel="stylesheet" />
       <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
       <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
       <script src="js/index.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
     </body>

   </html>
   nil
```

Answer (score 1):

In Enlive, you can write templates in [simple HTML](https://github.com/cgrand/enlive/blob/master/examples/net/cgrand/enlive_html/example.html):

Then just swap in the content with enlive template rules:

```
(deftemplate microblog-template
 "net/cgrand/enlive_html/example.html"  
 [title posts]
 [:title] (content title)
 [:h1] (content title)
 [:div.no-msg] #(when (empty? posts) %) 
 [:div.post] #(for [{:keys [title body]} posts]
              (at %
                [:h2 :a] (content title)
                [:p] (content body)))
   [[:a (attr? :href)]] (set-attr :title "it's a link"))
```

Finally, just return the result with:

```
(apply str (microblog-template "Hello user!" 
           [{:title "post #1" 
             :body "hello with dangerous chars: <>&"}
            {:title "post #2" 
             :body "dolor ipsum"}]))
```

So, in the first HTML template, just write the necessary imports for javascripts and CSS files. 
Note that you can also define re-usable sub-templates to stay DRY.

Comment: Yes, I know about this, and I can change content for title tag, because I can use selector for it, but I need append, and not content, but nodes to a parent node.

Answer (score 1):

So, I've found a way to add media resources per template. In my base template I have non-html tag , and I in a template file for the page there is such "more-media" section with needed stuff and snippet will insert it into a base template with (content) and finally I do (unwrap). A little bit tricky, but it works and there is no html data in the clojure code.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution although I'm far from being an Enlive pro (just started a couple of weeks ago) so please bear with me.

The following transformation assumes `link-includes` is a sequence of `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/this-page-custom.css">` (with appropriate values).

```
[:head] (html/append
          (for [link link-includes]
            (-> link
                html/html-snippet)))
```

tl;dr: I started with a brand new project using `lein2`.

```
jacek:~/sandbox
$ lein2 new stackoverflow/add-to-head-section
Generating a project called stackoverflow/add-to-head-section based on the 'default' template.
To see other templates (app, lein plugin, etc), try `lein help new`.
```

And added `[enlive "1.0.1"]` to `project.clj` (plus `:main` namespace so `lein2 repl` starts in the namespace):

```
jacek:~/sandbox/add-to-head-section
$ cat project.clj 
(defproject stackoverflow/add-to-head-section "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]
                 [enlive "1.0.1"]]
  :main stackoverflow.add-to-head-section.core)
```

I borrowed a simple HTML template from [Twitter Bootstrap's Getting Started](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/getting-started.html#html-template) and saved it in `src/stackoverflow/add_to_head_section/index.html`.

```
jacek:~/sandbox/add-to-head-section
$ cat src/stackoverflow/add_to_head_section/index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The last puzzle was to write an Enlive script in `src/stackoverflow/add_to_head_section/core.clj` as follows:

```
(ns stackoverflow.add-to-head-section.core
  (:require [net.cgrand.enlive-html :as html]))

(html/deftemplate index-html "stackoverflow/add_to_head_section/index.html"
  [link-includes]
  [:head] (html/append
            (for [link link-includes]
              (-> link
                  html/html-snippet))))

(defn render-index-html []
  (index-html ["<link rel='stylesheet' href='/css/this-page-custom.css'>"
               "<link rel='stylesheet' href='/css/another-custom.css'>"]))

(print (apply str (render-index-html)))
```

Once `lein2 repl` is up, the last `print` function kicks in and prints the expected outcome.

I might've been using Enlive's `sniptest`, but as I mentioned I'm yet to get used to it.