# Enlive templates - how to append script to end of the page

Tags: clojure, enlive

I am adding custom backbone.js scrips to my pages  and it needs to be at the end of page,

I have viewed the solution for adding scripts to the html head as described here : [Enlive templates – add to head section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978260/enlive-templates-add-to-head-section)

Unfortunately, I need to add scripts to page bottom.

```
<html>
   <head><!-- all the normal css and js scripts--></head> 
   <body> 
      <div> <!-- html content that will be used by my scripts --> </div>
      <!-- this is where i want to append custom javascripts  -->

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just realized its as simple as a conj :
My solution is non idiomatic and i added a lot of prints to understand what is under the hood ; once i figured out [:body] input to a transformer was a vector, conj became an obvious solution,

```
(html/sniptest "<html><body><header class=\"some_class\">Header Content</header><footer>sddsd</footer></body></html>"
    [:body] (fn [html-source]
              (let [conts (:content html-source)
                    newstuff  {:tag :script
                               :attrs {:src "../javascripts/foundation/foundation2.forms.js"}
                               :content []}
                    _  (pprint conts)
                    _  (print (class  conts))
                    conts2 (conj conts newstuff )]
                (assoc html-source :content conts2))))
```